# Relationship Checks when Mocking EF Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I'm wondering if there is any way to simulate foreign key checks when unit testing a Repository on top of EF using Moq? I have the following code which should technically fail because one of the relationships isn't present in either the database or the mocked sets on the context.

```
var entitySet = new Mock<DbSet<MyEntity>>();
var mockContext = new Mock<MyContext>();
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Set<MyEntity>()).Returns(entitySet.Object);
var myentity = new MyEntity
{
    RefID = "ABCD", //Foreign Key that does not exist in the context
};

var repo = new MyRepo<MyEntity>(mockContext.Object);
repo.Add(myentity);         

//repo.Add()
public void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    DbSet.Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I would expect this code to fail since an object with the reference ID doesn't exist but it succeeds and any verifies that I add to mockContext also succeed. I'm not sure then what purpose unit testing this pattern serves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're mocking the `DbSet`, you need to tell it that you want an exception to happen.

In other words, the mocked `DbSet` will behave (since you are using [loose](http://codebetter.com/aaronjensen/2008/03/26/moq-s-mockbehavior/) mocks) as if everything is fine; a mocked `DbSet` has no concept of foreign key constraints--much less your domain's specific constraints--since it isn't really a `DbSet`, and so an error will never occur.

To tell the mocked set that you want an exception on `Add`, you'd need to setup `entitySet` like this:

```
var myentity = new MyEntity
{
    RefID = "ABCD", //Foreign Key that does not exist in the context
};
entitySet.Setup(p => p.Add(myentity))
         .Throws(new YourForeignKeyConstraintException());
```

---

To have your `SaveChanges` method throw, just add this line instead of the one above:

```
mockContext.Setup(p => p.SaveChanges())
           .Throws(new YourForeignKeyConstraintException());
```

Comment: So I would have to add my own foreign key checking essentially? I guess maybe I don't understand what happens when I call SaveChanges() on my mocked context. In the live non-mocked version it's that method on the context that does the FK checking but it doesn't do it in the mocked scenario so what function does it actually perform?

Comment: Calling a method on a mocked object does only what you set it up to do.  If you didn't set it up to do anything explicitly (and you're using loose mocks), then it will do *nothing*.  Mocking may not be what you're looking for here.

Comment: I see what you're saying and it makes sense and the mocking approach would work better for testing queries. Is there an alternative to testing the add function? I guess I could add and delete to the actual database but that seems to defeat the spirit of writing these tests in the first place.

Comment: Well, testing the actual database is a good thing to do in an integration test, i.e. a test that might require external dependencies and isn't expected to run fast.  In the unit test however, you need to figure out exactly what you're trying to test.  Is it the handling of the FKC exception when you call `SaveChanges`?  If so, make the exception happen similar to how I showed above.  If it's something else, I can't help without more details.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to test was that if I added an entity that violated an FK constraint that context would throw an error. I  could achieve that by having my mock context throw on SaveChanges but doesn't seem to actually be testing very much.

Comment: What if I have retry logic in my code?  If I catch an exception that gets thrown by SaveChanges(), then in the catch block, fix up the data, and retry, how can I test that?  If I set up SaveChanges() to always throw the exception, the retry logic will never succeed and will thus not be fully tested.

Comment: @JoeMjr2 Ask a new question, that's too much to answer in a comment.

Comment: I couldn't find "entitySet.Setup" function in my context

Comment: @Tunaki I appreciate, you got me correct, thanks dude.........i am removing it from answer section.